# What is FreeBSD MD5 and why does it produce hashes in non-hexadecimal notation?

Tags: cryptography, md5, freebsd, hash-function

I am doing a hacking challenge from Hack This Site in which I found a password hash and then cracked it by brute forcing possibilities. The format that my hash cracker (John the Ripper) used was something called "FreeBSD MD5". The password and hash are the following:
PW: shadow
HASH: $1$AAODv...$gXPqGkIO3Cu6dnclE/sok1

My question is, doesn't MD5 normally only have the charset 0123456789abcdef (hexadecimal)? Why is this hash suddenly including a bunch of other characters?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a salted password hash:

- $ is a field separator
- 1 is the type (MD5)
- AAODv... is the (plaintext) salt for the hash
- gXPqGkIO3Cu6dnclE/sok1 is the hash coded in base64

The salt is concatenated with the password before hashing to prevent rainbow tables: md5(salt + password)) and to verify a password, it must be prefixed with this salt prior to hashing.

Representing the hash in base64 makes it a bit shorter than by hex digits (23 vs 32 bytes).

Comment: Jeez, salted hashes should have occurred to me- I suppose I'm not experienced enough in crypto yet. Why would the base64 representation take up less space, though? It certainly would have less characters, I suppose- is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, less characters and thus less space in a textfile like `/etc/shadow`

Comment: I see- and hex digits are stored as 8 bits, not 4 bits, in text files due to the encoding?

Comment: Yes, each char in a textfile uses 8 bits (on common systems, anyway). So, less chars -> space saved